# Add css style to xhtml from resources

Tags: css, jsf, resources

I am new to jsf. I have an xhtml login window which direct you to a welcome site. On the welcome site I want to style according to the css file which lays under webcontent - resources - css.

I have made an link to the css file in the head

```html
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
```

and then I give a heading an id and attach a color to the id in the css file. But it does not work.
The funny thing is that it works when I want a heading in my login window. 
What am I doing wrong in welcome?

Login:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>#{msgs.title}</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h3 id="name">#{msgs.heading}</h3>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Welcome:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>#{msgs.title}</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form >
            <h3>
                #{msgs.welcome}
                <h:outputText value="#{userBean.user.name}" id="name"/>
            </h3>
        <h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

.name {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should never have worked in both cases. You've specified a CSS class selector `.name`, but you haven't specifyed a `class="name"` anywhere. You've only specified an `id="name"`. The CSS class selectors won't select elements by ID.

So, there are 2 solutions:

1. Replace the class selector `.name` by ID selector `#name` in your CSS:

   ```css
   #name {
       color: blue; 
   }
   ```
2. **Or**, replace `id="name"` by `class="name"` in normal HTML elements and by `styleClass="name"` in JSF components:

   ```html
   <h3 class="name">
   ```

   and

   ```html
   <h:outputText styleClass="name">
   ```

Option 2 is semantically more correct in your particular markup. You should never use the same ID on semantically completely different elements throughout the entire website.

#### See also:

- [W3 CSS Selector documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)